# Application in background and after reboot is not working

Tags: android, startup, autostart, oppo

I have turned on startup manager https://colapps.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/217203146-OPPO-F1-No-Notificatons-Startup-Manager
 and 
battery optimization  option

Permissions given:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

Boot complete Recevier

```
 <receiver android:name=".Utilities.BootCompletedIntentReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and Battery optimization code:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                String packageName = getContext().getPackageName();
                PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getContext().getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
                if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                    i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
```

in Settings but still it is not working.In Oppo Application is not working in background and after boot. I had tested on MI device, code working fine. Is there am I missing somthing

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue did same things as you but just one more extra one.

```
intent.setClassName("com.coloros.oppoguardelf",
                                           "com.coloros.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerConsumptionActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

call above intent, it will redirect you to battery option, "Disable Background Freeze, Abnormal Apps Optimization and Doze from \"Energy Saver ->youAPP"

Note: Once you call above intent, there you may get different options to turn off Battery saving options.

thanks :)